# NameError: name 'language' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

```
import wikipedia

def IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
if language in wikipedia.languages():
    return True
else:
    return False

def LanguageSetup(language):
if IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
    wikipedia.set_lang(language)
else:
    return False

def CountWordsInPage(page):
return len(page.summary.split())

def MaximumCountWordsOnPagesAndTitle(names):
maximum = -1
title = ""
for name in names:
    count = CountWordsInPage(wikipedia.page(name))
    if count >= maximum:
        maximum = count
        title = name
        return f"{maximum} {title}"

def IsPageAvailable(name):
try:
    wikipedia.page(name)
except Exception:
    return False
return True


def CreateChain(names):
chain = [names[0]]
for index in range(len(names) - 1):

    page = wikipedia.page(names[index])

    if names[index + 1] in page.links:
        chain.append(names[index + 1])
    else:

        for link in page.links:

            if not IsPageAvailable(link):
                continue
            intermediate = wikipedia.page(link)

            if names[index + 1] in intermediate.links:
                chain.append(intermediate.title)
                chain.append(names[index + 1])
                break
return(chain)

input = ['Чуумпу далай', 'Хоту Америка', 'Континент', 'sah']
# input = input().split(', ')
if not IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):
    print('no results')
else:
    LanguageSetup(input[-1])
    print(MaximumCountWordsOnPagesAndTitle(input[0:-1]))
    print(CreateChain(input[0:-1]))
```

Comment: У вас не существует переменной language, больше здесь сказать нечего.

Answer (score 0):

Исключая проблему отступов на листинге, ваша программа не знает о переменной `language` в этой строке `if not IsLanguageExistInWikipedia(language):`